# Is "To Forgive is the only way to forget" an authentic quote of the Buddha?

Tags: virtue

" ***To Forgive is the only way to forget*** "

Is this one of the sayings of *Lord Buddha*. This quote is beautiful, but I couldn't find the source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt it -- I expected it ought to be listed in https://fakebuddhaquotes.com/ if I could say that without being harsh.

There is something pretty like it, IMO, though not as quotable, in the Dhammapada -- e.g. [this translation](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.01.budd.html):

> 1. Mind precedes all mental states. Mind is their chief; they are all mind-wrought. If with an impure mind a person speaks or acts suffering follows him like the wheel that follows the foot of the ox.
> 2. Mind precedes all mental states. Mind is their chief; they are all mind-wrought. If with a pure mind a person speaks or acts happiness follows him like his never-departing shadow.
> 3. "He abused me, he struck me, he overpowered me, he robbed me." **Those who harbor such thoughts do not still their hatred**.
> 4. "He abused me, he struck me, he overpowered me, he robbed me." **Those who do not harbor such thoughts still their hatred**.
> 5. Hatred is never appeased by hatred in this world. **By non-hatred alone is hatred appeased. This is a law eternal**.
> 6. There are those who do not realize that one day we all must die. But those who do realize this **settle their quarrels**.

After a while you begin to guess whether a quote is "fake" -- partly from knowing the prose style of the suttas a bit, and partly from knowing what themes the Buddha does and doesn't talk about.

The Buddha doesn't talk about "forgiveness" exactly -- more about other themes including:

- Don't take injury "personally"
- Don't "accept" (e.g. participate in receiving or giving) insults
- Don't get angry (nor hostile) in the first place
- Feel kindness, be kind, towards other people -- kindness, but also equanimity, and seeing good in them, and not wanting to hurt them